# gnuplot: x11 terminal in "interactive mode" while calling gnuplot from shell

Tags: gnuplot

I want to call gnuplot with a shell command, all the commands are stored in, let's say, "load.gp".

If I start the gnuplot shell and type "load 'load.gp'" I can change the viewpoint by dragging the splot with the mouse around.

The Problem is, I can't figure out how to reach that without being in the gnuplot shell.

```
echo "load 'load.gp'" | gnuplot -persist
```

or

```
gnuplot -persist 'load.gp'
```

won't work. Can somebody help me?

Thanks, Jan

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
gnuplot load.gp -
```

does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
gnuplot -persist load.gp
```

should do the trick just fine...

Sounds like you have some error in your load.gp file. Try setting the terminal in your load.gp file. Perhaps it the terminal remains unset or is set to a terminal incompatible with the commands in y our file. all fail, post your load.gp file here, and let's have a look at it :)

/B2S

Comment: This is the correct way to keep the plot displayed but the gnuplot prompt is not presented to the user.

Comment: Indeed, as he requested. I don't see why this answer was voted down... surely if he doesn't get the desired results, an error in his load.gp file is a plausible reason.

Comment: As I interpret it, the OP would like to be able to run a script and have that run finish with a zoomable plot. Persist does not, at present, allow zooming.

Comment: That depends entirely on the terminal you choose to use. Using the 'wxt' terminal allows zooming just fine with the -persist flag

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an hyphen after the command, e.g.

```
gnuplot -persist 'load.gp' -
```

As mentioned here: http://old.nabble.com/gnuplot-in-persist-mode-td28289021.html