# switch to terminal input after executable gnuplot script

Tags: unix, gnuplot

This is a gnuplot scripting question on unix like systems.
For shell executable gnuplot scripts starting like:-

```
#!/opt/local/bin/gnuplot
```

how do you switch to the gnuplot prompt in the starting terminal session, at the end of the script?

Adding 
`load "/dev/stdin"`
at the end, switches the input, but gives no user prompt.

I would like to let the user replot their own data over the setup and background generated by the script, and/or enter other gnuplot commands.  I am looking for an elegant solution within gnuplot.  When using the `#!/opt/local/bin/gnuplot -c` in a gnuplot scriptfile (after a chmod +x), I would like `./script.gp` to work the same way as `call "script.gp"` from gnuplot does. This is so we could subsequently `replot "info.dat"` at a gnuplot prompt in each case.  I want to switch gnuplot from batch mode to interactive at the end of the script (probably like in the way a startup file would).  I can't remember or find the command/trick for this (`load "/dev/stdin"` is close).

The plot window in this case is AquaTerm, gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 3 (macports), and the terminal session is OS X "Terminal".  --persist seems unhelpful in changing the experience.

Comment: Related: [gnuplot: x11 terminal in “interactive mode” while calling gnuplot from shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362910/gnuplot-x11-terminal-in-interactive-mode-while-calling-gnuplot-from-shell)

Comment: Consider adding the `expect` tag to your question as I suspect there is an elegant solution using it.

Answer (score 2):

You want to send a load of plot commands from a file to **gnuplot**, then send a load of commands from your user's terminal, which suggests something like this:

```
{ cat plot.gp; while read cmd; do echo "$cmd"; done; } | gnuplot
```

Or if I flesh that out a bit:

```
{ cat plot.gp; while :; do >&2 echo -n "gnuplot> "; read -re c; [ "$c" == "quit" ] && break; echo "$c"; done; } | gnuplot
```

I am using this `plot.gp`

```
set xrange [-5:5]
plot sin(x),cos(x),x*x
```

---

That basic functionality can be spruced up quite a lot, if you feel fancy:

```
#!/bin/bash
gpfile=$1

{
   # Show user gnuplot version - on stderr because stdout is going to gnuplot
   gnuplot -e "show version" >&2

   # Strip shebang (but not comments) from plot commands and send to gnuplot
   grep -v "^#!" "$gpfile" 

   # Show plot commands from file to user - on stderr and prefixed with pseudo-prompt
   grep -v "^#!" "$gpfile" | sed 's/^/gnuplot> /' >&2

   # Read user input and forward onto gnuplot
   while :; do
      >&2 echo -n "gnuplot> "
      read -re c
      [ "$c" == "quit" ] && break
      echo "$c"
   done
} | gnuplot
```

[image]

You would save the above in a file called `plotandinteract` in your HOME directory, then make it executable (just once) with:

```
chmod +x $HOME/plotandinteract
```

Then you can run it with:

```
$HOME/plotandinteract SomePlotFile
```

There's probably a much more elegant solution with `Tcl/expect` but I can't work that out - looks like I need @GlennJackman again :-)

Comment: I am impressed!  However, I am looking for a solution within gnuplot which might work with shebang on unix and guplot>`call "script.gp"` on other systems.

Comment: The *enhanced* last version of my script works with scripts containg a shebang.